# ASP.NET CORE Web API Fails to return file but instead it returns text

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have to export the list users as a CSV file.

Here is my Sample.cs

```
   `public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }`
```

Here is my controller code and sample data.

```
   `
  private IList<Sample> sample = new List<Sample>
    {
        new Sample {Id=1,Name ="pons",Email="pons@gmail.com"},
        new Sample {Id=2 ,Name="maddy",Email="maddy@hotmail.com"},
        new Sample {Id=3,Name="thom",Email="thom@malinator.com"},
        new Sample {Id=4,Name="gomz",Email="gomz@outlook.com"},
        new Sample { Id=5,Name="vaandu",Email="vaandu@gmail.com"}
    };
   [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetValue")]
    public IActionResult ExportToCSV()
    {

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.AppendLine("Id,Name,Email");
        foreach (var data in sample)
        {
            builder.AppendLine($"{data.Id},{data.Name},{data.Email}");
        }
        return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString()), "text/csv", "god.csv");`
```

The above code is expected to return a file (automatically download a csv file).It returns a text instead of a file.
Here is the output of the above code
[image: Response to postman by above controller]

This how it return to my angular request
[image: Response b y the above controller to angular request]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be FileContentResult instead of IActionResult

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetValue")]
public FileContentResult ExportToCSV()
{

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendLine("Id,Name,Email");
    foreach (var data in sample)
    {
        builder.AppendLine($"{data.Id},{data.Name},{data.Email}");
    }
    return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString()), "text/csv", "god.csv");`
```

Comment: Can you please share your angular download file request code? Because in API code there is no issue.

Comment: In postman, there is an option to save the response as a file, and if you direct hit this API URL in a web browser. then it's CSV file download with your current code. Please check

Comment: export()
  {
    return this.http.get(environment.ApiUrl+"Values/GetValue")
  }
This is how I call the above service method
onSubmit()
{ this.service.export().subscribe(
    res=>{},
    err=>{}
  );}

Comment: Okay. So you need to use Blob. [Please refer to this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/export-json-to-csv-file-in-angular/)

Comment: Is there any way to return a csv file from api controller  directly?

Comment: Your code already returns the csv file. In another way, you can save the CSV file in the server and send it to the file path or convert file content into base64 and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a file from ApiController, I returned a list as Response to angular,displayed it in a table and exported that table using table exporter package.

[Table exporter implementation](https://codezup.com/angular-7-8-9-export-table-data-csv-json-text-excel/)

For Angular version more than 9(up to 12) Don't forget to add **matTableExporter** attribute as below

**<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"  matSort    matTableExporter #exporter="matTableExporter">**

This satisfied my requirement.